# How to pip install google cloud exceptions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have this import statement in python:
`from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound`
I get this exception:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.exceptions'`
My pip freeze has the following lines:

```
google-api-core==1.14.3
google-auth==1.7.1
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-tasks==1.3.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
```

What should I do / pip install to make this work?

Comment: Looking the issue I would like to propose you to check [this](https://techoverflow.net/2019/01/26/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-cloud-iam/). Bear in mind is not official documentation written by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `google-cloud` to your `requirements.txt` file.

The module was renamed from `google.cloud` to `google.api_core` so your import will look like the following:

```
from google.api_core.exceptions import NotFound
```

Answer (score 1):

According to docs: https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/core/exceptions.html, you can just do `pip install google-cloud` and then in python file, `from google.api_core.exceptions import <YOUR_EXCEPTION>`

you're missing `.api_core` in your import